# ObjectID with conventions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to generate ids with a convention, for example:

Instead of getting: "538cd180e381f20d1c1cd2a2"
I would like to have an ID like this one: "p38cd180e381f20d1c1cd2a2"

So what I want is that my IDs start with a consonant letter.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that within the driver, I mean, getting that behaviour on "new mongo.ObjectId()"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don´t know whether this is possible, but might I ask WHY you need this?

Comment: Neither do I. I'm using other tool and seems like this tool has some inner Validations, so I need to give it what it considers a "Valid ID" that is one that start with a consonant. I was just wondering if there is a way to do it within the driver, and not without the driver, just to have less messy and personal code in this part.

Comment: The ID you list as valid, isn't valid because it starts with a `p` (which isn't a hex character).  Methinks you're off in the weeds as no decent MongoDB tool would require that of an ObjectID.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you @JohnnyHK, but the ID is not valid for the other tool ( far away from mongodb ), the "valid id" is valid for the other system, but not for mongo and now I realize that is not possible to achieve that behaviour on mongo.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** Sorry, no standard way available to achieve this as of now.

**Detailed answer and workaround:** MongoDB or driver generated ids are a combination of Creation Time (as timestamp), Increment value for next id, Machine on which the id is generated and the process id of the process which generated this document id. All this info is available in the generated id and can be extracted back. For now, this is what you have been given and there is no support for generating your own custom id from the driver's algorithm.

If you want to customize your id generation and be able to make use of these properties, then you can embed all this info that MongoDB uses for id generation and add this information to your document itself. By doing that you will be able to reproduce the information that MongoDB generates from the id. And while inserting the document to MongoDB, you can give your docs a customized id which agrees with your requirements.

So if you later on want to make comparisons based on creation time or maybe the machine, you can do that from the information that was added to the docs themselves.

Comment: So there is no way to mess around with that, thanks.

Comment: @rahpuser: yes, no standard way. only workarounds. a good one is mentioned below of doing `db.collection.insert({"_id":"p"+new ObjectId()})`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, to get the id starting with a consonant

db.collection.insert({"_id":"p"+new ObjectId()})

you can use any other string in place of "p" and the string will append to the start of the id generated by mongodb.

Comment: You can use anything as ``_id``, but you need to ensure that it's unique. And it might screw up other features like ``DBRef`` so you should try to avoid using your own ``_id``. Why not prepend the ID with *p* when you're communicating with the other system and add / remove it as required?

Answer (score 0):

Use the code: `db.collection.insert({"customId":"p"+new ObjectId()})`. And let your code use this customId.